# Java jagged array count numbers bigger limit

Tags: java, arrays

I want to count the number of integers bigger than a limit in a Jagged java array.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int limit = 2;
    int[][] a = {{1,2,3}, {2,3,4,5,6}};
    ArrayLimit bigger = new ArrayLimit();
    bigger.numberBiggerLimit(a, limit);
    System.out.println(bigger.numberBiggerLimit(a, limit));
}
public int numberBiggerLimit(int[] [] a, int limit) {
    int biggerLimit = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] > limit) {
                biggerLimit++;
            }
        }
    }
    return biggerLimit;
}
```

}

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Please describe your problem more in details so you can get a better help.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your second loop to `for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length...)`  instead of `for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length...) ` in order to make your code work, if that's what you asking. But that main method does not makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace `a[0].length` to `a[i].length` in the inner loop. But next time, please, ask more accurately.

```
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] > limit) {
            biggerLimit++;
        }
    }
}
```